# Set 2 colors to a Checkbox text possible?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, checkbox, colors

I want to set 2 color to a Checkbox text :

```
if (this.checkBox4.Checked) {
    this.checkBox4.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    this.checkBox4.Text = "Max Parameters on set ON";                 
}
else {
    this.checkBox4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    this.checkBox4.Text = "Max Parameters on set OFF";

}
```

I want to set ON to Green and OFF to Red

Thanks

**Edit:**

Yes it's in the Form1.cs

```
private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] buffer;
    if (this.checkBox4.Checked)
    {
        this.checkBox4.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        this.checkBox4.Text = "Max Parameters Points on set ON";
        buffer = new byte[] { 0x90, 0xc3, 0, 12 };
        PS3.SetMemory(0x53e088, buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        this.checkBox4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        this.checkBox4.Text = "Max Parameters Points on set OFF";
        buffer = new byte[] { 0x90, 0x83, 0, 12 };
        PS3.SetMemory(0x53e088, buffer);
    }
}
```

And in the Form1.Designer.cs there is :

```
// checkBox4
    // 
    this.checkBox4.AutoSize = true;
    this.checkBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 109);
    this.checkBox4.Name = "checkBox4";
    this.checkBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(165, 17);
    this.checkBox4.TabIndex = 2;
    this.checkBox4.Text = "Max Parameters points on set";
    this.checkBox4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.checkBox4.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox4_CheckedChanged;
```

Comment: Whats the problem in that. Put this code in checkbox's state change event and you will get it.

Comment: @SharadAg. quite correct, but it is the `CheckedChanged` event :-)

Comment: Actually it change all the Checkbox text color and i just want to set ON to Green OFF to Red and the rest to black.

Comment: You want only word on/off in green and red and rest text in black?

Comment: @M4DM4N Having only parts of the text in color is way trickier. See my answer for a possible method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have multi-colored text in a WinForms Control you need to draw the control yourself. The following code was automatically translated from VB.NET, but should work. You need to add this as a new class to your project and compile it. Then you should see a new control in your Designer Toolbox. You probably need to set `AutoSize` to false for the control and adjust the width.

The result:

[image]

It needs some tidying up, but you should get the idea.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class MultiColorCheckbox : CheckBox
{

    public MultiColorCheckbox()
        : base()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        this.AutoSize = false;
        this.Width = 50;
    }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        //Draw background
        using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor))
        {
            pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, this.ClientRectangle);
        }

        //Draw the checkbox
        ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(pevent.Graphics, new Rectangle(1, 1, 16, 16), this.Checked ? ButtonState.Checked : ButtonState.Normal);

        //Measure the base string
        Font f = this.Font;
        SizeF s1 = pevent.Graphics.MeasureString("Max Parameters on set ", f);
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(18, 1, (int)s1.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height - 2);

        //Create string format
        using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
        {
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap;
            sf.Trimming = StringTrimming.None;

            //Draw base string
            pevent.Graphics.DrawString("Max Parameters on set ", f, Brushes.Black, r1, sf);

            //Draw secondary string, based on check state
            if (this.Checked)
            {
                SizeF s2 = pevent.Graphics.MeasureString("ON", f);
                Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle((int)r1.Right, 1, (int)s2.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height - 2);
                pevent.Graphics.DrawString("ON", f, Brushes.Green, r2, sf);
            }
            else
            {
                SizeF s2 = pevent.Graphics.MeasureString("OFF", f);
                Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle((int)r1.Right, 1, (int)s2.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height - 2);
                pevent.Graphics.DrawString("OFF", f, Brushes.Red, r2, sf);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you sir ! Couldn't do it without help

Comment: @M4DM4N No problem. If that solved the question, you should click the checkmark on this answer to mark your question as answered.

Comment: Work great thanks had few errors but managed to fix them. I had to use the Tosize() method to convert the SizeF to Size because the Rectangle methode can't take float as parameter.

    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(r1.Right, 1, s2.ToSize().Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height - 2);

Comment: My last edit actually included the casts to int. Don't cast to string if you need an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you put it that code.
If you put that code on `CheckBox.CheckedChanged` or `CheckBox.CheckStateChanged` events, you can get a result what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's in your `checkbox4_CheckedChanged` event. This is how it should look:

```
 private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.checkBox4.Checked == true)
        {
            this.checkBox4.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            this.checkBox4.Text = "Max Parameters on set ON";

        }
        else if (this.checkBox4.Checked == false)
        {
            this.checkBox4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            this.checkBox4.Text = "Max Parameters on set OFF";
        }
    }
```

You can double click on the checkbox in the design view to generate the event in code view.

Answer (score 0):

See if you want to have multicolored text in checkbox u have probably 2 options:

1.If using asp.net pasa the color value in html/css form and it will do(most probably)

2. If you want the aame thing in winforms then there's a bad  news for  u. You will have extend checkbox component and redraw using GDI+. Search on net u will get some articles on customised checkboxes in c#
3. Create a new user control with a checkbox and a rtfbox. Or a checkbox and 2 lables and align them intelligently.

Comment: Yeah that's what i found when i searched on the problem but didn't wanted to to that but i guess i don't have the choice.